# mysql many counts from subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select query, but i want to have in results also several counts as column: count how many t3 rows assosiated with t1 row and how many t3 rows assosiated with t2 row. And the result should have columns: t1t3Count, t2t3Count. For first row t1T3Count should be equals to 5, and t2t3count

```
create table t1 (id int, name text);
insert into t1 values(1, 'name1');
insert into t1 values(2, 'name2');
create table t2 (id int, t1Id int, name text);
insert into t2 values(1, 1, 't2name1');
insert into t2 values(2, 1, 't2name2');
insert into t2 values(3, 2, 't2name3');
create table t3 (id int, t2Id int, name text);
insert into t3 values(1, 1, 't3name1');
insert into t3 values(2, 1, 't3name2');
insert into t3 values(3, 1, 't3name3');
insert into t3 values(4, 2, 't3name3');
insert into t3 values(5, 2, 't3name3');
insert into t3 values(6, 3, 't3name3');

   mysql> select * from t1 join t2 on(t1.id=t2.t1Id) join t3 on(t2.id=t3.t2Id);
+------+-------+------+------+---------+------+------+---------+
| id   | name  | id   | t1Id | name    | id   | t2Id | name    |
+------+-------+------+------+---------+------+------+---------+
|    1 | name1 |    1 |    1 | t2name1 |    1 |    1 | t3name1 |
|    1 | name1 |    1 |    1 | t2name1 |    2 |    1 | t3name2 |
|    1 | name1 |    1 |    1 | t2name1 |    3 |    1 | t3name3 |
|    1 | name1 |    2 |    1 | t2name2 |    4 |    2 | t3name3 |
|    1 | name1 |    2 |    1 | t2name2 |    5 |    2 | t3name3 |
|    2 | name2 |    3 |    2 | t2name3 |    6 |    3 | t3name3 |
+------+-------+------+------+---------+------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're after.  Please show your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, If i understand correctly you want to count the total occurrence of all items from t1 into both t2 and t3 right?

if so, the data provided must result in

name1 = 5 {2 in t2 and 3 in t3} and 
name2 = 3 {1 in t2 and 2 in t3}

If the above is what you want then this is what you want

```
SELECT 
      t1.id, t1.name, 
      COALESCE( t2Counts.t2Count, 000000 ) + COALESCE( t3Counts.t3Count, 000000 ) AS total_occurences_in_t2_and_t3
   FROM
      ( SELECT @t2Countt := 0,
               @t3Countt := 0
        ) sqlvars,
      t1
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT t1Id, COUNT(*) AS t2Count
                       FROM t2
                       GROUP BY t1Id ) AS t2Counts
           ON t1.id = t2Counts.t1Id

        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT t2Id, COUNT(*) AS t3Count
                       FROM t3
                       GROUP BY t2Id ) AS t3Counts
           ON t1.id = t3Counts.t2Id
```

And if I got you wrong better [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448695/how-to-optimize-query-if-table-contain-10000-entries-using-mysql/10449699#comment13534637_10449699) it has much more explanation

Hope this will help you.