# How to include "declare" syntax in a MySqlCommand

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to declare a local variable in a MySqlCommand but the variable keeps getting interpreted as a parameter, so an exception is thrown saying the parameter wasn't initialized. I'm trying to do something like:

```
comm.CommandText="declare @mid int; etc.....";
```

`@mid` is a local variable, not a parameter but somebody at MicroSoft thought it would be a good idea to use an @ to prefix parameters.

Comment: You could turn that code into a stored procedure (which seems reasonable since you need local variables), then invoke that procedure through your command.

Comment: I wonder why that didn't occur to me. Thanks!

Comment: Note, this is not Microsoft's fault but the writer of whatever library you are using to connect to MySQL and you should report this to them.

Comment: Variables with the `@` prefix in MySQL are called "user-defined" variables.  They are untyped, and cannot be declared, so your usage here would not be valid at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows variables to be created inline to your query, you would just have to build the statement with whatever value you want and can then adjust within the query as if it was an in-line variable.  It is up to YOU to control and know / change the data types...  Something like..

```
select
      a.field,
      @var1 := @var +1 as sampleIncrease,
      @var2 := DATE_ADD( @var2, INTERVAL @var1 DAY )
   from
      someTable a,
      ( select @var1 := 1, 
               @var2 := now()  ) sqlvars
   where
      ...
```

[Here is another example from my post posts showing a variety of uses of mysql variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448695/how-to-optimize-query-if-table-contain-10000-entries-using-mysql/10449699#10449699)